# How to sum a variable by group and make sure if every variable in a group is a NA the sum is NA instead of zero?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have data as the following example:

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | NA|
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | NA|
| 4 | NA|
| 4 | NA|
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | NA|
| 5 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |
```

I need to create a new data frame by summing `b` dependent on `a` and if every data in a group is NA the output should be NA instead of zero, like this:

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | NA|
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 0 |
```

How can I structure a sum in R to behave like this?

Thank you

Comment: can you please add a dput of your initial data?

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(. ~ a,
  df, 
  function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
  na.action = na.pass
)
```

gives

```
  a  b
1 1  1
2 2  1
3 3  0
4 4 NA
5 5  2
6 6  0
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L), b = c(1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L,
1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
´``
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mean_` from `hablar`

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)
df %>% 
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarise(b = sum_(b))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     3     0
4     4    NA
5     5     2
6     6     0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L), b = c(1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L,
1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```